# Does Popen.communicate() implicitly call Popen.wait()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

In the Python 3 Documentation, it states under https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

> Wait for process to terminate.

Does this mean that `Popen.communicate()` also calls `Popen.wait()` such that I can take a shortcut by not writing `p2.wait()` before `p2.returncode` and do:

```
  p0 = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/svn", "info"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  p1 = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/grep", "Revision:"], stdin=p0.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  p2 = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sed", r"s/Revision: //g"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
  stdout, stderr = p2.communicate()# implicitly calls p2.wait() to wait for exit code?
  info_struct.exitcode = p2.returncode
```

instead of

```
  p0 = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/svn", "info"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  p1 = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/grep", "Revision:"], stdin=p0.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  p2 = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sed", r"s/Revision: //g"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
  stdout, stderr = p2.communicate()# implicitly calls p2.wait() to wait for exit code?
  p2.wait()# explicit wait for exit code call
  info_struct.exitcode = p2.returncode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. See the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Lib/subprocess.py#L796-L842) (Python 3.6.1 version linked):

```
sts = self.wait(timeout=self._remaining_time(endtime))
```

You do not have to call `p2.wait()` yourself, the process has terminated by that point.